# Linux on an USB drive: Advantages of Rufus?

Tags: system-installation, usb-drive, debian-installer

I have a USB flash drive with a Debian install. Not a "live" system, but a normal full install.
I made it with the normal Debian installer, by choosing the USB drive as "hard disk" to partition. And while I made no extensive statistics, I guess that can be done with many Linux distributions even if they don't use debians installer.

At the same time, I've seen plenty information, questions, blogs, and whatever praising this "Rufus" software as the ideal (and sometimes only) way to get such a USB Linux. Doing it without any third-party software isn't ever mentioned.

So what is the great advantage that I fail to see? Why no one ever recommends installing normally?

Comment: I don't mean that the USB holds a ISO and something to load it to RAM (that would, in my eyes, be a live system that doesn't save changes over reboots). Instead my USB holds ext4 partitions, Grub etc., like Debian on a internal hard disk would.

Comment: And btw. if I wanted a live system, I still could copy the ISO on some ext4 partition and use grub to load it. But there at least I can see why some people prefer a software doing the configuration - it's just some lines, but still something to learn.

Comment: I think we have some weird disagreement here. "normal installations have been done by booting from USB or DVD, then running installation script."  Yes that is what I did, and that is why I called it normal. Even in 2021. Just my install target was not the internal hard disk, but a USB drive. And I'm not asking about Windows, but Debian here.

Comment: I posted an answer. If that satisfies, please do accept it so we get this out of the Unanswered-queue. If not, please feel free to comment. I will be deleting my comments here as they no longer serve a purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Rufus dev here.

The problem with `dd` and utilities that only perform `dd`-like write of ISOHybrid images is that it can result in drive content that are very confusing for Windows users, and that actually leads them **not** to try to boot their media because they (wrongly) assume that it was improperly created.

This is answered rather extensively [in the relevant Rufus FAQ entry](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Why_doesnt_Rufus_recommend_DD_mode_over_ISO_mode_for_ISOHybrid_images_Surely_DD_is_better) and, AFAIK, this is not something that is being considered by folks who don't interact regularly with Windows users.

Also, one thing that needs to be pointed out is that for `dd` to work, the ISO must have been mastered as a *ISOHybrid*, which is technically a hack (albeit a brilliant one) to make something (an unpartitioned optical media file system) appear like something it was never designed to be (a partitioned disk file system).

This is the reason why, for instance, you can't simply pick a Windows ISO and expect `dd` to work for creating a USB boot media, because Windows ISOs are not mastered as ISOHybrid.

So, despite what one may be tempted think, there exist drawbacks to only seeing an ISO as a `dd` image in disguise, and that is where Rufus can help, especially with first time Linux users coming from Windows.

I also have to point out that, ideally, on a UEFI system, one should really not have to deal with sector by sector copy, as the whole point of UEFI was to stop the madness of needing to work with bootloaders operating at the sector level and instead have UEFI bootloaders always operate at the file system level, which means that one should be able to simply extract the ISO content to a FAT32 drive, and get that to boot (which, actually, is a method that Debian maintainers have done a fairly good job of supporting).

Unfortunately, that is not the case for all distributions, especially the ones that look for the Linux boot media by label, but this is something that Rufus can also help with, without having to write the media in `dd` image mode.

In short, and unlike most of the other boot media creation utilities I know (but then again, as the main developer of Rufus I may be a bit biased in that view) Rufus does not concentrate on a few specific cases, such as ISOhybrid images that are designed to work well when copied in `dd` mode, but instead tries to do a decent job at also supporting less straightforward cases, as well as ensuring that Windows users, who may be wanting to try Linux, don't end up in the unfortunate situation of thinking that, because Windows will not mount the underlying ISOHybrid file system, the media they just created is not going to work.

Oh, and Rufus does also provide some additional features that might make it attractive to some, like the ability to download retail Windows installation ISOs straight from Microsoft, or the ability to download a UEFI Shell, or the ability to create a DOS drive, or the ability to save a drive as a VHD (which is really a `dd` image in disguise anyway), or the ability to write a compressed `dd` image, or the ability to compute the MD5/SHA-### of the selected image, or the ability to run a bad blocks check, and other things, that may not be directly relevant to Linux users, but that, as a whole, probably contribute to seeing it being recommended.

Answer (score 2):

When I'm working on Linux and need to create a bootable USB stick to install another OS, I can simply use `dd`. Windows users aren't as lucky, the OS doesn't contain anything like it.

That's where Rufus comes in. It's not a tool you use to install an OS, it's a tool you use to create an OS installation media. Since there's no native way to create a bootable USB stick and put an ISO there, you need a 3rd party solution. It's not the only available tool, but it's been around for a long time and it's known to be reliable.

Rufus is a Win-only tool. So any articles, blog posts, videos and whatnot where you see it used are targeted to Windows audience. Linux-centered media tends to point to `dd` instead.